# Instagram API - get ALL users for specific hashtag or location

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've started looking into the Instagram API and I want to pull out ALL users that have used a specific hashtag or have been at a given location.

As the documentation says I can get the RECENT users for a hashtag and location using the following methods:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?access_token={token}

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&access_token={token}
```

I am getting the recent (up to 7 minutes old) data with these. My question is if it is possible to retrieve ALL users, not just the recent? Also, how can I get media objects for a name of a location, for example "London"? It seems like I have to get the location ID of the location first, but the documentation doesn't make it clear how to get the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getting users by hashtag or location

To my knowledge, there isn't a tidy endpoint for getting user data by hashtag or location. I think the only way to get all users from the Tags, Locations, or Geographies recent media endpoints is to slaughter the API and scape the `user` object from each item in the `data` array from each paginated response on those endpoints. There's a `pagination` attribute on the same level as `data` in each response that helps you do this.

`"pagination":  {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1009570282366298753",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1009570282366298753",
    "next_min_id": "1009570411710268632",
    "min_tag_id": "1009570411710268632",
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?access_token={access_token}&max_tag_id=1009570282366298753"
  },`

`pagination.next_url` is going to get you another page of responses later than the current response, which will have a new `pagination.next_url` and so on.

You can pass an additional parameter in your GET URL `?count=33`, this specifies the number of objects you get in the `data` array, the max is 33. So you can get 33 results per request instead of the default 20 per request.

### Getting Location IDs

The Location Media Recent Endpoint only works on location ID, but location ID can be found in the `location` property of an object in the `data` array from any recent media endpoint. That property will only be populated if that image was geo-located and a location was specified, which are different to the Instagram API.

It'd probably be easier just to use the [location search endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/) and search through the results until you find the location your looking for.

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&distance={radius_in_meters}&access_token={access_token}`