# How can I check location of instagram followers/following

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, instagram, instagram-api

I want to be able to make this request from Instagram

- check all following
- check location tags in last 7 days
- check if in -insert city-

I want to be able to track the location of my followers/people I follow, possibly generate a map

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30901598/4229270

Comment: What have you looked into already to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm completely inexperienced with this area. I have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://gramfeed.com and lookup users (followers/following), click on `Show Map` it will geolocate all the photos that have a place tagged, based on that you can estimate the location

[image: gramfeed user geolocation]

Comment: The problem with this is if you follow around 1500 people then the webpage only loads 14 hours worth of your total feed. I also just want a list of names rather than having to click numerous times

Comment: btw, well feed API will be deprecated after June 2016, so better not to depend on that

Comment: Any other ideas? Or where/who I could ask? Been trying to figure this out for ages...

Comment: you can create app so that u can select a follower and then get location, one by one

Comment: use documentation for instagram api: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Can I pay someone to do this?